# jquery- operating on added inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I have one row with input fields in table and user can add new rows (copy of first) by clicking button.
Script to adding new row:

```
var row = '<tr><td>'+number+'</td>'+f1+f2+f3+f4+f9+f5+f6+f7+f8+'</tr>';
$('#table').find('#tbody').append(row);
```

In first row I can do some calculations with data in inputs but in added i can't do anything.
Script for calcs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[name="name['+rowSelected+']"]).delegate('keyup',{}, function(){
  some calculations
});
```

I'm trying with .delegate and .live without success. I need help to solve this problem.

Comment: This can't even be executed. Look at the quotes.

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you want to delegate on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would use `.on()` for handling of dynamically added `input` tags in the table:

```
$("#table").on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    // code here for all input tags in the table
});
```

You can adjust the `'input'` selector if you need to narrow it to only some of the input tags in the table.

For `.on()`, you use this form:

```
$(static parent selector).on(event, selector for dynamically added objects, handler fn);
```